# sql including row even if values are null MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating a query that gets the amount of retired people per fiscal year.
Let's say I have this table:

```
 table1

|  FY   |  Reason for leave |
|2011-12|       sick        |
|2011-12|       retired     |
|2011-12|       retire      |
|2012-13|       sick        |
|2014-15|       retired     |
|2014-15|       retired     |
|2014-15|       retired     |
```

My Query is:

```
Select FY, Count(*) FROM table1 WHERE [Reason for leave] = "retired";
```

The problem is it won't return 2012-13 as one of the fiscal years, which makes sense, but I'd like for it to include all the years with either 0 or a blank as the count column

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Side note: I recommend you change your column type for `FY` to either `int`, `char(4)`, or `Date`. Basically store the fiscal year, not the year range *which adds no benefit*. Using `int` or `date` (*set to month = 1, day = 1*)  will make it possible to constrain values, filter values, and also perform calculations. If you really must then use `char(4)`. What you have in there now makes it possible for an application error (or manual update) to enter an invalid value like `2015-14` and you won't know until you discover that a query result does not return what you were expecting.

Comment: thanks great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a separate table of years you could left join to your table1. If you don't, you could use something like this:-

```
select FY, sum (iif([Reason for leave]="retired",1,0)) as Count_Retired
from table1
group by FY;
```

Comment: Thanks alot I can't believe I didnt think of that!